# In Android, Image is getting blur after zooming it by using chrisbanes PhotoView library

Tags: android, image, zooming, photoview

I want to display set of images in horizontal viewpager.
I have used the "chrisbanes PhotoView" library.
Everything is working well but after zooming any image the quality of images getting lose even for high resolution images.

The Size of image is 1440*2560

Please let me know, if I am missing something[image]

Thanks you in advanced